# Zest Graphical Framework - Graph View Based on Previous Graph

Tags: java, eclipse, graph, eclipse-rcp, zest

I am trying to create a "Go Back to Previous Graph" option for my RCP application which uses the Zest graphical framework.

There is a base graph, which it starts out with, and more detailed graphs the user can interact with. Once the user is at a certain graph, and wants to go back to the previous one shown, they can click the go back button - fairly simple, I'm sure you all understand.

I store graph data in the form of an Arraylist of Lists of the nodes on the graph, and another Arraylist of Lists, storing the connection data.

How can I use these stored datas to get my GraphViewer to use these, instead of the current data set?